# Non-linear SVM is not available in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, svm, apache-spark-mllib

Does avyone know the reason why the Non-Linear SVM has not been implemented in Apache Spark?
I was reading this page:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4638

Look at the last comment. It says:

*"Commenting here b/c of the recent dev list thread: Non-linear kernels for SVMs in Spark would be great to have. The main barriers are:
Kernelized SVM training is hard to distribute. Naive methods require a lot of communication. To get this feature into Spark, we'd need to do proper background research and write up a good design.
Other ML algorithms are arguably more in demand and still need improvements (as of the date of this comment). Tree ensembles are first-and-foremost in my mind."*

The question is: Why is the kernelized SVM hard to distribute?

Everybody knows that the non-linear SVMs exhibit better performance than the linear ones.

Comment: I have the same question .. A spark noob here , we have 2 bil + records and want to use non linear kernel trick for the data, only way out is spark mllib for now, would love to see such a feature